# Converting epoch to human-readable date doesn't work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, epoch

I am using **time module** to convert epoch into human readable date using the code below.

```
import time
datetime = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", time.localtime(1609740000000))
print(datetime)
```

```
>>> Thu, 17 Aug 52980 20:00:00 +0000
```

The output is incorrect when I check it on https://www.epochconverter.com

Correct output should be **Wed, 04 Aug 2021 21:49:24 +0000**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.localtime` takes time in seconds. You presumably pass time in milliseconds.

```
datetime = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", 
                         time.localtime(1609740000000 // 1000))
#'Mon, 04 Jan 2021 01:00:00 +0000'
```

The answer from epochconverter.com is the same. **Your** "correct output" is incorrect.

---

[image]

Comment: Hi DYZ, I just double checked that the correct answer is indeed correct. please check out this link. https://www.epochconverter.com/?q=1609740000000

Comment: You must be looking at the wrong place on the page. See the updated answer.

Comment: You're right, I was looking at the text holder below that. Bad UI design! Thanks for your help